# How to define links for social network icons on flexdashboard?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I added social icons to navbar for a flexdashboard, but there's no way to add an appropriate link for each of them.

in an R Markdown file, I added:

```
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
      social: [ "twitter", "facebook", "linkedin" ]
```

How can I add links for each social network?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
---
title: "Manoj Kumar"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    navbar:
        - { icon: "fa-question-circle", href: "https://google.com", align: right }
        - { icon: "fa-twitter", href: "https://twitter.com/YourAccount", align: right}
        - { icon: "fa-linkedin", href: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/YourAccount", align: right}
runtime: shiny
---
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with so far is to use

```
- { icon: "fa-twitter", href: "link to my twitter account",align: right}
```

It works but maybe there is a better alternative out there.