# How to align social links properly on Flexdashboard

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I am trying to embed social links on a `flexdashboard` and I get the following:

[image]

```
---
title: "Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    css: ["default", "assets/css/my-theme.css", "assets/css/my-fonts.css"]
    orientation: columns
    navbar:
        - { icon: "fa-github", href: "https://github.com/", align: center }
        - { icon: "fa-youtube", href: "https://www.youtube.com/", align: center}
        - { icon: "fa-linkedin", href: "https://www.linkedin.com/", align: center}
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: 
      version: 3
      bootswatch: yeti
runtime: shiny
---
```

Is there a way to properly align it to the right side? Mine appears to be on a newline.

I came from this post: [How to define links for social network icons on flexdashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234380/how-to-define-links-for-social-network-icons-on-flexdashboard)

Comment: Have you tried `align: right`?  
  
A reprex maybe useful here. Your css files may be changing the default behavior. I tested using your layout specs (exl. css files) on a template and the icons displayed on the right.

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggestion, I just moved to the `left` to solve the alignment issues.